# Google Directory API: Is it possible to list all the Groups-Members relations in one request?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

When managing a Google Directory with tons of Users and Groups, I'm looking for a way to list the relations between both with the minimum of requests as possible, currently I have to request a list of existing Groups and then issue some other requests get the Members for each.

I'd like to achieve this by only issuing 1 request which could return the member_id and the group_id for each relation, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not possible. does not appear in the api docs.

Comment: thanks! I actually read the documentation and was trying to see if there were any custom query or something else I was not aware about with which I could fetch such information